# Count unrepeated elements on mysql group by

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
| id | metrictimestamp | vehicleid |
+----+-----------------+-----------+
|  1 |  20180201025934 |     33089 |
|  2 |  20180201025955 |     34489 |
|  3 |  20180201025959 |     32040 |
```

I need to group by date(metrictimestamp) and count how many unrepeated "vehicleid" there is for each day, any sugestions?

Comment: I suggest you try something! For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Have you even tried anything???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DISTINCT in your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT metrictimestamp) FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert your metrictimestamp field into a date type that mysql understands:

```
STR_TO_DATE(metrictimestamp, '%Y%m%d%h%i%s')
```

next you need to extract the date portion of that field and give it an alias (date):

```
DATE(STR_TO_DATE(metrictimestamp, '%Y%m%d%h%i%s')) date
```

finally you need to group by the resultant `date` and the `vehicleid` and filter by repeated records (so only include singletons), so putting it all together:

```
select DATE(STR_TO_DATE(metrictimestamp, '%Y%m%d%h%i%s')) date, vehicleid from group_test_table group by date, vehicleid having count(vehicleid) = 1;
```

If I misunderstood your question and you only want the unique vehicleids for any date then:

```
select distinct DATE(STR_TO_DATE(metrictimestamp, '%Y%m%d%h%i%s')) date, vehicleid from group_test_table group by date, vehicleid;
```